# Difference between discount_amount and discount_amount_cart?

Tags: paypal

What is the difference between `discount_amount` and `discount_amount_cart`? I've checked the [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/) but can't seem to understand the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`discount_amount` applies to Buy It Now and Add to Cart.

`discount_amount_cart` applies to Cart Upload.